# How to display data in DataGrid returned from SQL Server (no code behind)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

New to SO and my first question.

I've spent a day researching and trying to figure this out. All examples I've found show putting everything in code behind with button clicks. Or some show putting SQL logic in ViewModel. I'm trying to keep SQL logic out of view and view models.

I have a textbox where user enters search value. That value is searched against SQL Server table. I see the values when using a breakpoint so everything is working up to that point. I just can't figure out how to display them in the DataGrid after that. The values are lost when exiting loop.

If I change autogenerate columns to "True", I see the column names so I think binding is set correct. It also shows a column of name HasErrors when setting to "True" which seemed strange.

How can I get this data to display in DataGrid? I think the problem is because I'm not returning those values but I'm unsure how to accomplish that in my current scenario. Am I going about this wrong and need to do this differently? Should I be using a DataReader instead?

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Person.cs

```
public class Person : ValidationBase
{
    private string lastname;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set
        {
            if (lastname != value)
            {
                lastname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string firstname;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set
        {
            if (firstname != value)
            {
                firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string emailaddress;

    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return emailaddress; }
        set
        {
            if (emailaddress != value)
            {
                emailaddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public static bool SearchUser(string UserLookupTextBox) //<-- Textbox value from ViewModel
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [LastName], [FirstName], [EmailAddress] from [User] where (LastName=@Lookup)", con))
    {
        var person = new Person();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lookup", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserLookupTextBox.Trim()             

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            person.LastName = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            person.FirstName = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            person.EmailAddress = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();

            //how do I return this to Person or to datagrid??
        };
    }  //<--Values get lost here

    return true;
}
```

ViewModel

```
    private ObservableCollection<Person> updateusersearch = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> UpdateUserSearch
    {
        get { return updateusersearch; }
        set
        {
            updateusersearch = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteSearchUser(object parameter) 
    {
        bool SearchUser = NewUserModel.SearchUser(UserLookupTextBox); <--passing textbox value to Model
    }

    public NewUserViewModel()
    {
        SearchUserCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSearchUser, CanExecuteSearchUser);
    }
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid //<--Cut everything else to keep short. Others columns identical setup
        DataContext="{Binding UpdateUserSearch}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Last Name"
                Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You should move `person` variable to class level

Comment: If you have an instance of your viewmodel, and that is set to the grid's DataContext, you just need to populate `UpdateUserSearch` with the results of your query. Do not loop over it and create rows, that defeats the point of binding.

Comment: @Crowcoder I do have that set in DataContext = new NewUserViewModel(); I can remove for loop. That is where I'm struggling though. I'm not figuring out how to populate UpdateUserSearch with the results.

Comment: In the loop create a new `Person` and add it to `UpdateUserSearch` each iteration. Stress  the "In the loop". You don't want to add the same Person instance each time.

Comment: @Crowcoder Whenever I try to add or return anything, I get error "cannot implicitly convert Person to 'bool'." I must be doing it wrong. Would you mind providing example?

Comment: [Look at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection). You may want to abstract your data access and create a hard-coded list of Person like in the example just for testing so you can focus on the problem. Once you have the binding working  you can figure out how to get your query results into the list.

Comment: You are assigning the firstname in the setter of the Email address

Comment: @pr177 sorry about that. it is correct in my code. Something got messed up on copying it over to the question. My apoligies. I am setting emailaddress there rather than first name. Thank you for catching. This is my first question so Im not sure how to edit yet but i will try to see how I can edit that.

Comment: You can return a list of users (depends if you want to show a list or just one) instead of bool. In the for loop fill the list and after return it. In the ExecuteSearchUser you can pass them to the observablecollection.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok thank you, let me see if I can figure that out with link you provided. Similar to what JohnyL mentioned. Frustrating having so much trouble for what seems like it should be a simple task.

Comment: You can completely change your approach and simplify it using Entity Framework. See this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574514(v=vs.113).aspx). It will separate the SQL logic from your models and mostly from the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Each of the commenters helped in one way or the other, thank you everyone for helping. I still feel there is a better way(aside from Entity Framework as mentioned). Hopefully others will add those ways in the future for others to find. I will also look in to EF for future as well. It seems like 80% or more of the material you find online shows you how to do things wrong. They teach you to write SQL injectable code. Use button clicks with WPF. Etc. There just needs to be so much more “good” content out there. Maybe this will help someone else at some point. It accomplished the goal for me of loading in datagrid.

Below are the changes made. If you don’t see it’s the same as posted in question. Other than I changed UpdateUserSearch to UserSearch so changed that in XAML and ObservableCollection.

View Model

```
private void ExecuteSearchUser(object parameter)
{
    LoadUserSearch(); 
}

NewUserModel.UserSearch model = new NewUserModel.UserSearch();
private void LoadUserSearch()
{
    DataTable table = model.GetUserData(UserLookupTextBox, SearchByComboBox);

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
        UserSearch.Add(new Person()
        {
            LastName = table.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
            FirstName = table.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
            EmailAddress = table.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
        });
    table.Dispose();
}
```

Model

```
public class UserSearch 
{
    public DataTable GetUserData(string UserLookupTextBox, string SearchByComboBox)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        if (SearchByComboBox == "Last Name")
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [LastName], [FirstName], [EmailAddress] from [DbUser] where (LastName=@Lookup)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lookup", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserLookupTextBox.Trim();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        ........
        }
    }
}
```

}